# Why wont this Code execute?

Tags: jquery

**This Run like it is perfectly fine.**

```
// Save, set state to finalized and Print
        $('#btnDialogPrint').click(function () {

            if ($('#chkFinal').is(':checked')) {
                $(function () {
                    $("#PrintDialog").dialog('close');    
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#chkFinal').attr('checked', true); // Set finalized. This checkbox is not visible its like a hidden field
                $('#btnSubmit').click(); // Save
            }

        });
```

**And this also runs fine:**

```
window.location = '../Print/' + $('#SalesContractId').val();
```

**But when i put them together it only run's the**

> **window.location = '../Print/' + $('#SalesContractId').val();**

**Complete Code:**

```
// Save, set state to finalized and Print
    $('#btnDialogPrint').click(function () {

        if ($('#chkFinal').is(':checked')) {

            $(function () {
                $("#PrintDialog").dialog('close');
                window.location = '../Print/' + $('#SalesContractId').val();    // Moves to ContractController Print
            });
        }
        else {
            $('#chkFinal').attr('checked', true); // Set finalized. This checkbox is not visible its like a hidden field
            $('#btnSubmit').click(); // Save
             window.location = '../Print/' + $('#SalesContractId').val();    // does not alow above code to execute 
        }

    });
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. Removing tags.

Comment: It is a mvc app, this is just the code in my js file

Comment: For future reference, if you can, post the code on jsfiddle.net.  it'll help us debug it much more quickly.

Comment: @Pomster, it doesn't matter that it's in an mvc project.  The problem, and code, are jquery/ javascript only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `$(function() { ... });` inside the click handler and put it **ouside**:

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnDialogPrint').click(function () {
        if ($('#chkFinal').is(':checked')) {
            $("#PrintDialog").dialog('close');
            window.location.href = '../Print/' + $('#SalesContractId').val();
        } else {
            $('#chkFinal').attr('checked', true);                
            $('#btnSubmit').click();
        }
    });
});
```

The `$(function() { ... });` means [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

This being said you seem to be calling some `$('#btnSubmit').click();`. Note that if this `#btnSubmit` is actually the submit button of some form (as its id suggests) then when the form is submitted it will automatically redirect the browser to the `action` attribute of the form. So it is completely meaningless to call `window.location.href` to redirect in this case. I guess you will have to rethink whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ahhhh ok Thanks i see, so i cant submit and then print directly after, with this code?

Comment: I moved the `window.location` inside the `if`. As explained in my answer it is meaningless to call `window.location` after submitting a form.

Comment: No, you can print, but you will have to wait first for the corresponding server side script to execute and once it has finished executing you could redirect to the corresponding location.